# Checking for polygon neighbors using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, polygon

Could you tell me how to check in ArcObjects same feature overlapping other feature like (Building OID 10 and Another building OID 11) i tried to like below code but i am not going to for other step.

```
IFeatureClass Building = pfwspace.OpenFeatureClass("CO_Building");
                IFeatureCursor bld_cur = Building.Search(null, false);
                IFeature bld_F = bld_cur.NextFeature();
                int BF = Building.FindField("BUILDINGFORM");
                int BU = Building.FindField("BUILDINGUSE");
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("ObjectID");
                dt.Columns.Add("Feature Class");
                dt.Columns.Add("TGID");
                dt.Columns.Add("Error Comment");
                int tgid = Building.FindField("TGID");
                ITopologicalOperator ptopo = bld_F.Shape as ITopologicalOperator;
                IGeometry pgeo = ptopo.Buffer(1);
                ISpatialFilter pslt = new SpatialFilterClass();
                pslt.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects;
                int count = Building.FeatureCount(null);
                pslt.Geometry = pgeo;               
                while (bld_F != null)
                {                   
                    string BF_val = bld_F.get_Value(BF).ToString();
                    string BU_val = bld_F.get_Value(BU).ToString();
                    string TGID_val = bld_F.get_Value(tgid).ToString();
                    if (BF_val == "9" && BU_val == "31")
                    {
                        IFeatureCursor f_cur1 = Building.Search(pslt, false);
                        IFeature feature1 = f_cur1.NextFeature();
                        IRelationalOperator relop = bld_F.Shape as IRelationalOperator;
                        relop.Overlaps(feature1.Shape);
                        if (Building.FeatureCount(pslt) > 0)
                        {


                            dt.Rows.Add(bld_F.OID);
                        }
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(f_cur1);
                    }                   
                    bld_F = bld_cur.NextFeature();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks good up to this point:

```
if (BF_val == "9" && BU_val == "31")
{
    IFeatureCursor f_cur1 = Building.Search(pslt, false);
    IFeature feature1 = f_cur1.NextFeature();
    IRelationalOperator relop = bld_F.Shape as IRelationalOperator;
    relop.Overlaps(feature1.Shape);
    if (Building.FeatureCount(pslt) > 0)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(bld_F.OID);
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(f_cur1);
}
```

IRelationalOperator Disjoint/Overlaps/Contains return boolean:

```
if (BF_val == "9" && BU_val == "31")
{
    IFeatureCursor f_cur1 = Building.Search(pslt, false);
    IFeature feature1 = f_cur1.NextFeature();
    IRelationalOperator relop = bld_F.ShapeCopy as IRelationalOperator; // use ShapeCopy not Shape

    if (!relop.Disjoint(feature1.ShapeCopy)) // use not Disjoint to indicate intersection
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(bld_F.OID);
    }
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(f_cur1);
}
```

You should always use IFeature.ShapeCopy instead of IFeature.Shape to ensure the link between the shape and the feature is broken, otherwise unexpected results can occur, this also includes the line: `ITopologicalOperator ptopo = bld_F.Shape as ITopologicalOperator;` which becomes `ITopologicalOperator ptopo = bld_F.ShapeCopy as ITopologicalOperator;`

Comment: If this answer has fixed your problem please mark as answered so that future users with the same problem can see that it helped. Thank you.